# Setting Up a Clickable Multiple Choice

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm new to JQuery and I have a question about the order of events with my code. I have a multiple choice question with 3 choices below it. I want the user to click on the correct answer. My problem is that if the user clicks on the correct answer **first**, then I don't want anything to happen if they then click on the other 2 boxes.

How would I do this? I believe I need an if statement, but I'm not sure how to set it up to do what I'd like. Any tips/help would be appreciated.

This is in my script section:

```js
$(".choices:not(#answer)").one("click", function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "red");
  alert("sorry, that's incorrect");
});

$(".choices[id]").one("click", function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "grey");
  $("#blank").remove();
  $("#blank2").append($("#answer"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="youyaku">
  <table id="regular" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        I have to go <span id="blank2"></span><span id="blank">____</span> the hospital.
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="choices">
        <span>for</span>
      </td>
      <td id="answer" class="choices">
        <span>to</span>
      </td>
      <td class="choices">
        <span>at</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: you can check by check box state.